# How do I get a once-per-make recipe (GNU specific stuff is fine)

Tags: static, makefile, gnu-make

My goal is to run a recipe once, before all other targets are executed, and preferably without creating a dummy file or adding a dependency to every target.

My initial thoughts was to define a target like the following:

```
once:
    stuff to do once

%: once

actual_target: actual dependencies
    actual_recipe
```

However I believe that will cause the `once` target to run once for every target, rather than once per make. So my second thought was to do the following:

```
once_default:
    stuff to do once
    make actual_default

actual_default: actual dependencies
    actual_recipe
```

And although this achieves the 'once-per-make' requirement, it only works for the default target. It seems silly to write a bash script to wrap `make`, as `make` should have this sort of functionality. (and touching a 'once' file *shouldn't* be needed, given the existence of `.PHONY`). This is something I only need for this one-off project, so GNU extensions are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put this in the makefile somewhere:

```
once:
    stuff to do once

Makefile: once
```

(I'm assuming the name of your makefile is "Makefile". If it isn't, adjust accordingly.)

If there is a rule for rebuilding the makefile, Make will run that first, then restart and run the target(s) you asked for. In this case you're not actually rebuilding the makefile, but Make doesn't know that.